# Call an executable from C++, and wait until it is done, on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, shell

I'm trying to write a program which, at some point, needs to invoke an external application via the system and wait until that other executable finishes. I pretty much want a C++ version of the python subprocess.call(...) method. I know that system() can invoke a command via the shell, but I don't know if it is able to block until the commands terminate. Anyone know the right way to do this?

I'm writing this for a Linux system, but if possible, I'd like it to be portable. Anyway, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just check the documentation http://linux.die.net/man/3/system

Answer (score 10, accepted):

system() waits for the command to finish:

http://linux.die.net/man/3/system

> system() executes a command specified in command by calling /bin/sh -c
>   command, and returns after the command has been completed. During
>   execution of the command, SIGCHLD will be blocked, and SIGINT and
>   SIGQUIT will be ignored.

Answer (score 3):

The popen command should work nicely for you: http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen